# prolog unary numbers - evaluating expression

Tags: prolog, successor-arithmetics

I am trying to understand Prolog and I came up to following situation. I have defined natural numbers (unary) in following way:

```
n(0).
n(s(X)) :- nat(X).
```

Which means that 0 is 0, s(0) is 1, s(s(0)) is 2 etc...

Then I defined predicate add:

```
add(0, Y, Y) :- nat(Y).
add(s(X), Y, s(Z)) :-
   add(X, Y, Z).
```

Which adds two unary numbers and result stores to Z.

Now I have following predicate "test" what demonstrates my problem:

```
test(s(0),0).
```

Then in interpret I type:

```
add(s(0),0,R). %result: R = s(0), which is correct
```

Then i try:

```
test(add(s(0),0,R), 0).
```

So the first argument should result in R = s(0), second argument is zero, so the whole expression should be evaluated as true, but prolog says false. I guess that it has something to do with the point, that the add(s(0),0,R) inside the "test" predicate does not evaluate the way I think. Could anyone please explain this to me or eventually provide some link that describes this behaviour? Thanks for any help!
Cheers.

Comment: Are you sure, you want to use noth, `n/1` and `nat/1` ?

Comment: What you have written here, is not your program. With this program, the question ?- add(s(0),0,R). will be answered by an error message.

Answer (score 0):

No, prolog does not work the way you assume it to.
When you ask

```
?- test(add(s(0),0,R), 0).
```

prolog tries to find a matching clause. However, there is no matching clause in your database, since `s(0)` does not match `add(s(0),0,R)`. Two structures can only match if the have the same functor.

`s(0)` has the functor `s` while `add(s(0),0,R)` has the functor `add`.